# Get substring with n chars before and after the found sequence

Tags: java, regex, window, substring

I have large String variable named `text`. I want to be able to check if `text` contains a specified `searchString` (e.g. "test") and to return all substrings with `windowSize` chars before and after the matches.

Example:

```
String windowSize = 5;
String text = "this is only a simple test. lorem impsum testing everything.";
String searchString = "test";
```

As a result i want the following output:

```
mple test. lor
ssum testing e
```

Additionally, it would be great to be able to have different types of output:

Only before:

```
mple 
ssum
```

Only after:

```
. lor
ing e
```

## Solution

Thanks to Peter Lawrey and SubmittedDenied i got my answer:

```
String windowSize = 5;
String text = "this is only a simple test. lorem impsum testing everything.";
String searchString = "test";

int i = -1;
while((i = text.indexOf(searchString, i+1)) > -1) {
    System.out.println(text.substring(Math.max(0, i - windowSize), Math.min(i + searchString.length() + windowSize, text.length())));
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use regex? String.indexOf() would be simpler and faster.

Comment: You are right, didn't think of the simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the location of a substring with the `indexOf(string)` method, this will also return `-1` if there is no such substring.

You'd want to do something like:

```
String windowSize = 5;
String text = "this is only a simple test. lorem impsum testing everything.";
String searchString = "test";
int i = -1;
while((i = text.indexOf(test, i + 1)) > -1)
{
    System.out.println(text.substring(i - windowSize, i + searchString.length() + windowSize));
}
```

You'll probably need to catch errors like if the first occurence of `test` is less than `windowSize` characters into the string.

Comment: This would lead into an infinite loop because `text.indexOf(test)` always returns the same result.

Comment: Ah of course, I'll edit the answer to use `indexOf(string, startindex)` - knew I forgot something!

Comment: You want `text.indexOf(text, i+1)`, you also want `Math.max(0, i - windowsSize), Math.min(i + searchString.length() + windowSize, text.length())` when a match is close to the start and/or end.

Comment: @SubmittedDenied, it needs to be `i+1` or you have another infinite loop. ;)

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I updated my question with the resulting solution.

Comment: If you're happy with this, you should mark this answer as the chosen one :)

Answer (score 1):

```
int windowSize = 5;
String text = "this is only a simple test. lorem impsum testing everything.";
String searchString = "test"; 
Pattern pattern = new Pattern ("(.{" + windowSize + "})" + Pattern.Quote (searchString) + "(.{" + windowSize + "})");
```

If you want to get just the before or just the after, use the 1st or 2nd matched group.  (The parenthasis marks the before and after regions.

Comment: If you want to match up-to-windowsize, then use this expression: new Pattern ("(.{," + windowSize + "})" + Pattern.Quote (searchString) + "(.{," + windowSize + "})"); // A comma before the windowsize

Comment: This would only match one, but you could add `+` or `*` to fix it pretty easily